# How do you solve the last puzzle in the workshop?

Tags: vessel

In [Vessel](http://www.strangeloopgames.com/), how do you solve the last puzzle with the big machine at your workshop? I'm able to get the machine to start generating the element that looks like XP liquid, but the process stops before I can get anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally was able to finish the puzzle thusly:

1. Get prepared, stack up on liquids, etc. A nozzle that shoots seeds will be useful, but is not really necessary.
2. Put button-pushing fluros on buttons for lava and green liquid.
3. Put a fluro seed above the green liquid nozzle, slightly to the right, so the liquid would fall into lava and produce gas. Get rid of the green liquid pushing fluro.
4. Create a red fluro that is afraid of the light.
5. Chase that fluro to the container on top right by spraying some green liquid underneath the ledges they stop on. Make sure to have the hatch open on top first, so the fluro would go in.
6. Create a blue fluro that is afraid of the light and make it go into the top left container. You can create it where the leaver is and it will hop in.
7. Close both hatches
8. Place button-pushing fluros on all buttons except the green liquid button.
9. Create a button-pushing fluro while standing on the ledge connected to the left entrance to the machine.
10. Quickly go and wind up the machine, then just as quickly jump into it before it closes.
11. You might need to wait a bit before the green gas will appear, but it should get there with ample time left.
12. Jump and stay in the middle. The fluros that are afraid of the light will die when the gas will appear in the chamber, and you will see liquid similar to XP liquid forming. Watch the rest of the cut-scene where a human-like body forms out of the liquid and then the end credits.
13. You have finished Vessel!

Comment: Thanks, this got me in the right direction. What I did different to finally get it to work was: Create 2 fluro's to the left of the big device (one for the waterpump, one for the green liquid button) and one fluro on the right (for the blue goo) so they start creating the gas and steam simultaneously as I only got steam on other attempts even though the gas was being generated. Like you, I just finished the game now!

Comment: You can skip steps 3, 6, probably 7, 9.

Comment: I think it is important to emphasize *stay in the middle* and *jump when the ingredients start spinning*.  I had done everything right, but standing slightly off center the process occurred and ended without any effect (which is dumb IMHO).

Comment: im getting frustrated, i tried for 3 h and red fluro keeps dying within 3 seconds. and the red goo is just gone AHHHH

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the intended design, but you can actually make it so that all the components are done while you are inside the chamber. The only thing you have to do is turn the cog near the machine to get it started.

This is accomplished by having a seed above green release that will cause it to fall to the right towards the lava, you don't need tons of it for gas.

The rest of it sounds like you have got, the rest is just setting up a button pusher fluro to hit the lava switch, accomplished by having 1 on all the other buttons. 
Yo can have the machine half ready, then when you see gas go into chamber start it and run into chamber.

Not sure if this is the intended use, but you are able to suck up the protoplasm fluro liquid.